# jquery show using one button - close by clicking anywhere

Tags: jquery, menu, popup, toggle

I trying to create a simple jquery show and hide box, using one button. I want the user to be able to click any where around the screen and the opened div will close.

has anyone created anything similar?

Comment: `$("*").on("click", function() { $("#divID").hide() });`

Comment: This is so helpful. thank you for your time. the working demo is particular helpful as I am new to jquery. How would I add a button? when the button is clicked the box would be shown, again if the user clicks anywhere or the button the box will hide.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a fiddle on how to handle pop up of boxes and attaching close events to page clicks. You can figure out easily if u go through the comments in fiddle.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ScriptShiva/zWXks/8/**

**HTML**
 1. Create three blocks
    -1.1 One for parent (In your case u have a body)
    -1.2   One for mask (Based on clicks on this box, we will hide the toggle box), Need for this is we don't want to hide the box when
    user clicks on the box itself, rather we hide it when a user clicks
    outside box anywhere on the page.
    -1.3   One for the box to toggle (This is box we are going to show/hide)
 2. Create a button (Shows box when hidden)

```
<div id='view-port'><!-- This might be your body -->
    <div id='toggle-mask'><!--Mask screen to trigger hide-->
        <h3>Click anywhere on mask to close</h3>
    </div>
    <div id='toggle-box'><!--DIV Box to show or hide-->
        <h3>BOX CONTENT GOES HERE</h3>
    </div>
    <button id='toggle-button'><!--DIV Button to trigger Show-->
        Show Box
    </button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#view-port{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#f00;
}

#toggle-mask{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:#00F;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
#toggle-button{
    margin-top:200px;
}
#toggle-box{
    position:absolute;
    width:60%;
    height:50%;
    margin:10% 20%;
    background:#fff;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#toggle-button').click(function(){ // Function for button click
    $('#toggle-mask').show();//Show mask, simple div for our close click
    $('#toggle-box').show(); //Show Box
});
$('#toggle-mask').click(function(){
    $('#toggle-mask').hide(); //Hides mask
    $('#toggle-box').hide();  //Hides Box
});
```

Comment: Please let me know if you are available for work. Kind regards Paul

Comment: I am a full time Web Designer & Developer, if u need any help i will be available at weekends

Comment: Can you tell me what im doing wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/paulobriendesign/KzeCn/   I am trying to create show and hide without using a html 5 button

Comment: U are making small mistakes. 1.Use <a href='#test'> as <a href='#' id='test'>. The reason being u can't use id in that way, the href u used is like a goto in page. Always use id='divID' syntax. Put href='#' because fiddle will throw u error if u link it to any other page, so link to top of this page (#).

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5Ng49/

SHOW and HIDE

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('*').click(function(){
        $('#div1').toggle();
    });
});
```

HIDE

## **js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('*').click(function(){
            $('#div1').hide();
        });
    });
```

SHOW and HIDE using Button and clicking Anywhere

## **HTML**

```
<div id="div1">dsfsd</div>
<input type="button" id="b1" value="Hide"/>
```

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('*,#b1').click(function(){
        $('#div1').toggle();
        if($('#b1').attr('value') == 'Show'){
            $('#b1').attr('value','Hide');
        }else{
            $('#b1').attr('value','Show');
        }
    });
});
```

Working Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5Ng49/1/

if you don't want button changing text than:-

## **HTML**

```
<div id="div1">dsfsd</div>
<input type="button" id="b1" value="Show/Hide"/>
```

## **JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('*,#b1').click(function(){
        $('#div1').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: The toggle one is pointless - he just wants the 2nd one that closes the div when anything is clicked.  He doesn't want it to open when anything is clicked or the page would be useless :p

Comment: This is so helpful. thank you for your time. the working demo is particular helpful as I am new to jquery. How would I add a button?  when the button is clicked the box would be shown, again if the user clicks anywhere or the button the box will hide.

Comment: Once again thank you! you are very helpful:) thanks again. Please let me know if you are available for hire . regards Paul

Comment: Sorry for the questions. but what would be the jquery library that works for this ? for example   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    As on the demo it does not show you what to add in the header

Comment: i used <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: or you can use <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  if you are satisfied you can make this as answer

Comment: select on left panel Frameworks & Extensions jquery version 1.9.1 and $('#test')->refers to id selector it means an element with id test check demo http://jsfiddle.net/KzeCn/1/ . i'm off now will talk to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$("#button").click(function(){

$("#show_hide").show(1000,function(){

```
$('body:not(#button)').click(function(){

$("#show_hide").hide(1000);

$(this).unbind("click");

});

});
```

});

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you show me this working using http://jsfiddle.net/?